# How much time is going to take a process - by WCF Service

Tags: wcf, time, estimation

I’m here with another question this time.

I have an application which builds to move data from one database to another. It also deals with validation & comparison between the databases.  When we start moving the data from source to destination it takes a while as it always deals with thousands of records. We use WCF service and SQL server @ server side and WPF @ client side to handle this.

Now I have a requirement to notify user with the time it is going to take based on the source database no: records (eventually that is what im going to create in the destination database) right before user starts this movement process.

Now my real question, which is the best way we can do this and get an estimated time out of it?

Thanks and appreciated your helps.

Comment: Measure how long one item takes on average. Multiply by the number of records to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

If your estimates are going to be updated during the upload process, you can take the time already spent, delete on number of processed records, and multiply by number of remaining records. This will give you an updating average remaining time:

```
TimeSpan spent = DateTime.Now - startTime;
TimeSpan remaining = (spent / numberOfProcessedRecords) * numberOfRemainingRecords;
```